# How to find my current location (latitude + longitude) on click of a button in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I have seen various code snippets which find outs co-ordinates from various methods like onlocationupdate() or onstatusChanged().... what i want is a simple code that fetches my current GPS co-ordinates on click of a button...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LocationManager mLocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                LocationListener mLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
                mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{        

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {           
            String message = String.format(
                        "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                        loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude()
                );
                Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }       
    }
```

Read this for detail http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the previous answer... :) now that i have got the location.... how can i plot the same on the map??? i want to plot two locations on map and also path between them...

Answer (score 12):

Yogsma's answer addresses how to receive automatic updates.  The link he references provides all you need, but here is the summarized version of how to do a manual update:

Assuming you've read the tutorials on how to make a button, then you simply need to add a listener for your button, and then have the listener call a function to query your location manager. The code below does it all inline to show you how, but I'd instantiate LocationManager somewhere else (eg your activity) and I'd create a separate method for the on click listener to call to perform the update.

```
// getLocationButton is the name of your button.  Not the best name, I know.
getLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // instantiate the location manager, note you will need to request permissions in your manifest
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // get the last know location from your location manager.
        Location location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // now get the lat/lon from the location and do something with it.
        nowDoSomethingWith(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
});
```

Of course you will also need to register your activity with the location manager service in your manifest xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: As adbantej points out in his response, the getLastKnownLocation() call will only get the last good location, which is a strong reason to instantiate the LocationManager elsewhere.  This will give it more time to actually get a valid update, but this call still provides no assurances on validity of data.  For this you will need to use the onLocationChanged() methods or onGPSStatusChanged methods of an implemented Location or GPS listener.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the previous answer... :) now that i have got the location.... how can i plot the same on the map??? i want to plot two locations on map and also path between them...

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html and http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The above links were pretty helpful... :)

Comment: This must be right answer for question asked, there are cases you may only current location when required, the above answer is for tracking, both cases are different

Answer (score 4):

There is no such mechanism to get the current location immediately on demand. Since you need to query the Netowork or the GPS provider which may take time to actually get the location.

One way is to use the getLastKnownLocation which returns immediately. However this location may be stale. Another way is to register for a PASSIVE_PROVIDER by which you get a location fix with the hope that some other application has requested for location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the previous answer... :) now that i have got the location.... how can i plot the same on the map??? i want to plot two locations on map and also path between them.

Comment: I'll just guess here (I'm not well versed with this one). You will have to use Google API's and use the Map View. Here is an example to plot a simple point : http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: One thing I'm not following... What does `getLastKnwonLocation()` *do*? Does it not make a request of it's own, it just merely checks if some *other* app has already updated the location? I thought the phone's gps was automatically updating location, and `getLastKnownLocation()` would merely access whatever the GPS last acquired? You say it may be `stale` but how can it be `stale` if it's grabbing what the phone's own GPS is saying?