# Create Button that gives you your location (Android Studio)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, location

I want to create a button that tells me exactly where my device is located, that I pointed it to a MapView and gave me the coordinates of the device, I do not know how to give the action to the `Button`. I tried to use the LocationListener but it gives me an error

For now this is code that I have:

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
 double latitude, longitude;
 Button myplacebtn;
MapView mapView;
 GoogleMap map;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
         myplacebtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myplacebtn);//Button --get my location

         mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get a MapView
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                map = googleMap;
                // Setting a click event handler for the map
                map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                        // Creating a marker
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                        // Setting the position for the marker
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        setCoordinates.setText(latLng.latitude + " , " + latLng.longitude);
                        latitude = latLng.latitude;
                        longitude = latLng.longitude;

                        // Setting the title for the marker.
                        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

                        // Clears the previously touched position
                        map.clear();

                        // Animating to the touched position
                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                        // Placing a marker on the touched position
                        map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                });
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);


                LatLng jerusalem = new LatLng(32.1105435, 34.8683683);
                CameraUpdate miLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(jerusalem, 11);
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(jerusalem));
                googleMap.animateCamera(miLocation);
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(jerusalem);

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, MY_REQUEST_INT);
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

                googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            }
        });



        }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

If someone has an example, or some indication where I can start writing the code, I would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you tell us what error is shown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find my current location (latitute + longitude) on click of a button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757565/how-to-find-my-current-location-latitute-longitude-on-click-of-a-button-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FusedLocationProviderClient coupled with location update request. More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

```
FusedLocationProviderClient locationProviderClient = 
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))  // 10 seconds
                .setFastestInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)); // 1 second

        LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        // your code here
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, 
                    locationCallback, null);
        }
```

In addition, if you want to get rid of some request permissions boilerplate code, I suggest you to try RxPermissions library https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions